# PHP: difference between getenv() and apache_getenv()

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I'm using an Apache 2 server and hosting a web app there. I'm setting some environment variables in my vhost by using the Apache `SetEnv VARIABLE value` command.

When looking to retrieve the value in PHP, I've some across two methods. [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) and [`apache_getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php).

Is there any real difference? Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Not sure what the point of have the `apache_getenv()` method is if `getenv()` works the same and allows your code to be server agnostic.

Comment: php has a lot of duplicate functions

Comment: @Dagon Yeah - just wondering if there is any reason I should choose one over the other, or if it literally makes no difference.

Comment: They are slightly different -->  Explaned Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php and Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php  --  You don't need Apache to run PHP -- Keep that in mind ;-)

Comment: @Zak I read the docs. I even linked to them in my question. Please read the question first. And  yes, I know I don't need Apache to run PHP, but that's the server environment I have right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getenv` [calls](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4027) `apache_getenv` if you're running the Apache SAPI, otherwise it asks the system.  So, no, there is no real functional difference. Stick with `getenv`.